# How to resize/create new partition with mounted partition on Hard Drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, gparted

[Gparted image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnxHx.png)

1. My /dev/sda1 is 465.76G space on Gparted which is Mount/Inuse
2. I need to create a separate partition of 60G space for kali Linux.
3. The Unallocated space can it be increased and used for installation?

I will be grateful if anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: what about increasing the size of the unallocated will that be possible ?

Comment: Yes, after you shrink /devsda1.

Comment: Arigatōgozaimashita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by unallocated space you mean there's actually free space outside /dev/sda1 then you can easily create a new partition. However, if /dev/sda1 is your only partition and really spans over your entire HDD, then I'm afraid you should've used LVM to be able to do online resizing.

Comment: The unallocated space is about 1.03MB, so i can create a new partition while that is outside /dev/sda1 ? 
Thanks

Comment: if there was more space on the drive, outside /dev/sda1, yes, you could've, but 1.03MB is really not enough for a new partition. shrinking /dev/sda1 live cannot happen without losing data. you can try resize2fs /dev/sda1 <newzize>, but more than surely you'll get a prompt saying online shrinking not supported

Comment: Thanks bro, you have been helpful, have figured it out.  Appreciate it.

Comment: please do share your solution for others to see

Comment: I created a bootable Gparted on my USB then boot it straight from my PC then got into the Gparted desktop i was able to create a partition of 80G on my /dev/sda1. Then on installation for kali linux i installed it directly into in the 80G space and worked perfectly... Thanks for the Help.